# In angularjs my click function is not working can anybody help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

alert in click event is not working. if i use alert outside of the function it will work.but i need this alert on button click. how to do it.?

My coding is here

```
<div ng-app="indexapp" class="main">
    <div ng-controller="timectrl" class="timediv">
        <li><a ng-click='go()'>Like</a></li>    
    </div>
</div>
```

my script

```
var app = angular.module('indexapp', []);

app.controller('timectrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.go = function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

Comment: You should probably just use a button tag if you don't need a uri.

Comment: Do you see any errors on browser console?

Comment: i have checked but it is not working for button too

Comment: @laszlokiss88 no i didnt get any error

Answer (score 1):

Try: href=""

See:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a

Havent tested yet.

Comment: this coding is working properly but if i do the same thing in my code it is not working @laszlokiss88

Comment: see this link this is my full coding its not working as u told by all http://plnkr.co/edit/5fEXhfTR8AMEgA0P9o3z?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `ng-click` should work here **IF** you click on the text 'Like' (because you applied `ng-click` to `<a>` rather than `<li>`).

If thats the case, move `ng-click` to the `<li>` item:

```
<li ng-click='go()'><a>Like</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="indexapp" class="main">
    <div ng-controller="timectrl" class="timediv">
        <li><a ng-click='events.go()'>Like</a></li>    
    </div>
</div>
```

And your controller,

```
var app = angular.module('indexapp', []);

app.controller('timectrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.events = {};
    $scope.events.go = function() {
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

Try this one.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5fEXhfTR8AMEgA0P9o3z?p=preview this is my full coding. can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: @MuthulakshmiLakshmi, You are not loaded angular in your plunker? Is that the reason for your problem? Make sure what are the errors on your page.

Comment: no in my original file i have included the angular file. there s someother prob there . i couldnt find it.